# enotez - Separating \endnotemark and \endnotetext : Bug?

Tags: endnotes, enotez

I would like to keep the text of my endnotes separate from the endnote marker. I tried to use the package `enotez` to do this, but I don't get the result I expect. It only ever displays the text of the final footnote. There is a MWE example of the problem below : have I misunderstood something, or is this a bug with the package?

**Note:** *Using the older `endnotes` package the below code produces the expected results. But I wanted to use `enotez` because it hyperlinks the endnote marker and is generally more customizable.*

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enotez} 
\begin{document} 

Sed maximus justo et vehicula sodales. Sed iaculis felis at neque lacinia luctus. \endnotemark[1] 

Curabitur efficitur dui nulla. Quisque facilisis dapibus purus, quis efficitur nibh.\endnotemark[2]

Mauris odio sem, posuere laoreet erat sit amet, varius bibendum urna.\endnotemark[3]


\endnotetext[1]{Two paths diverged in a wood} 
\endnotetext[2]{And I took the one less travelled by} 
\endnotetext[3]{Or so I thought. Now I'm not so sure}
\printendnotes*


\end{document}
```

### Result :

[image: Actual result. Only one endnote is produced.]

### Expected Result :

[image: Expected result.All three endnotes should be produced]

Comment: It's not a bug. You *can* separate the mark and the text, because in some contexts it's the only way to proceed. But as soon as you state a new `\endnotetext`, the previous one gets forgotten. There *is* a reason why the full endnote has to be in the text: in the way you propose, the document will be very difficult to maintain, because you'd need to keep care of inserting the numbers and the texts in the precise order and if you decide to add an endnote between two already set, you need to change all numbers.

Comment: Yes this did occur to me - is there a (better) way of getting this kind of functionality? The `enotez` docs talk about `sepfootnotes` but I have never used this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. You can separate the mark and the text, because in some contexts it's the only way to proceed. But as soon as you state a new \endnotetext, the previous one gets forgotten. There is a reason why the full endnote has to be in the text: in the way you propose, the document will be very difficult to maintain, because you'd need to keep care of inserting the numbers and the texts in the precise order and if you decide to add an endnote between two already set, you need to change all numbers.

You might use `sepfootnotes`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\newendnotes{atend}
\atendnotecontent{1}{Two paths diverged in a wood} 
\atendnotecontent{2}{And I took the one less travelled by} 
\atendnotecontent{3}{Or so I thought. Now I'm not so sure}

\begin{document}

Sed maximus justo et vehicula sodales. Sed iaculis 
felis at neque lacinia luctus.\atendnote{1}

Curabitur efficitur dui nulla. Quisque facilisis 
dapibus purus, quis efficitur nibh.\atendnote{2}

Mauris odio sem, posuere laoreet erat sit amet, 
varius bibendum urna.\atendnote{3}

\section*{Notes}
\theatendnotes

\end{document}
```

However, I don't find this particularly appealing. The arguments, here numbers, can be any string you want.

[image]